# How to add Tags to Struct by function in golang

Tags: json, go, reflection, struct

I receive data from REST.body -> encoding data with json.Unmashal to Struct like below then create data to file.txt. Then i can search when file.txt created.
My problem: keys in struct too many from 1 - 50 like below. I don't know how to solve it. Some recommend is use map[string]string but i dont wanna change Struct to map.

```
type Items []Item

type Item struct {
    Id        string `json:"id"        required:"true"`
    CompCd    string `json:"compCd"    required:"true"`
    OrgCd     string `json:"orgCd"`
    QstnId    string `json:"qstnId"    required:"true"`
    QstnIdSeq string `json:"qstnIdSeq" required:"true"`
    CustId    string `json:"custId"`
    AnsDts    string `json:"ansDts"    required:"true"`
    AnsRout   string `json:"ansRout"   required:"true"`
    QCd01     string `json:"qCd01"`
    QKey01    string `json:"qKey01"`
    QStc01    string `json:"qStc01"`
    QCat01    string `json:"qCat01"`
    Pont01    string `json:"pont01"`
    PCat01    string `json:"pCat01"`
    Comt01    string `json:"comt01"`
    QCd02     string `json:"qCd02"`
    QKey02    string `json:"qKey02"`
    QStc02    string `json:"qStc02"`
    QCat02    string `json:"qCat02"`
    Pont02    string `json:"pont02"`
    PCat02    string `json:"pCat02"`
    Comt02    string `json:"comt02"`
    .
    .
    .
    QCd50  string `json:"qCd50"`
    QKey50 string `json:"qKey50"`
    QStc50 string `json:"qStc50"`
    QCat50 string `json:"qCat50"`
    Pont50 string `json:"pont50"`
    PCat50 string `json:"pCat50"`
    Comt50 string `json:"comt50"`
}
```

Comment: You should not be using a struct for Item; instead, use a map[string]string. That way, the fields are dynamic (just like they are in JavaScript).

Comment: By the way, it is not possible to add tags at runtime in Go. That's because, as I said, you should use maps for cases like this.

Comment: thanks u for recommend

Answer (score 3):

As Alex mentions, it is not possible to add tags at runtime. However, Fatih (creator of  the vim extension for go, vim-go) has a cli-tool to modify the tags of a struct. [Here is the repo](https://github.com/fatih/gomodifytags/blob/master/README.md), maybe it could help you.

Comment: I think i will try to do on your recommend using import github.com/fatih/gomodifytags. The work follow is: use vim to import Item struct into github.com/fatih/gomodifytags, then import github.com/fatih/gomodifytags into my file code.go. Can it will work?